# Copying files and folders with cp with shopt extglob - error is not a directory

Tags: command-line, bash, cp

I'm trying to copy files from a directory while excluding a folder and a file. My problem is that a get an error with shopt extglob activated. Here is my code:

```
DEPLOY_SIMULATION_ENV="/home/user/Desktop/fancyproject/"
shopt -s extglob
cp -r ./!(nbproject|zexp.html) "$DEPLOY_SIMULATION_ENV"
shopt -u extglob
```

It gives me

```
‘/home/user/Desktop/myfancyproject/’ is not a directory
```

Of course, I want cp to create the directory **myfancyproject** atuomatically. I have a workaround with **mkdir $DEPLOY_SIMULATION_ENV** first but is there a way to do it with cp? It behaves strangely when **extglob** is active.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure the problem is not the usage of "user" here...

```
DEPLOY_SIMULATION_ENV="/home/user/Desktop/fancyproject/"
```

If the account name is not "user" it will fail with the same error as you show. You need `$USER` if you want the actual user.

---

> Is there a way to do it with cp

Yes... but not how you expect it.

> --parents
>
> Form the name of each destination file by appending to the target directory a slash and the specified name of the source file. The last argument given to cp must be the name of an existing directory. For example, the command:

```
      cp --parents dir1/dir2/file1 dir3
```

will create `/dir1/dir2` inside `dir3` (needs to already exist) and copy `file1` into it.

Comment: Oh, it is such a stupid mistake of mine. I just forgot about --parents and -p. But anyway, yes, the user exists. Thanks!